# Network log shows 404 at beginning of load for folders within wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

Within my wordpress site, I have a folder called projects.  Whenever I access a page within the projects directory, the first response in the log is a 404.  While this appears to have no impact on the page, it seems to mean that search engines aren't indexing these pages, as they first response they get from the page is a 404.

For example:

http://www.caseyrule.com/projects/sounds-of-sorting/

If you open the javascript console and look at the network log, you'll see that the first response is a 404 for the page itself, followed by all the assets of the page loading successful.

[image]

I tried adding a line to the .htaccess to exclude that directory from rewrites for the projects folder, but that didn't fix the problem.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(projects) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas what could be going on here?

**Update:** I've been doing some experiementing and it seem that the only pages on which I am seeing this error are pages that include `wp-blog-header.php`, in order to make use of the wordpress functions such as `wp_nav_menu` and `get_search_form`.

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';
```

It is still not clear to me though why this would result in cause the first response from the page to be a 404.

Comment: By the way, I liked to play around on your project !!

Comment: You should try `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`. Check for example [this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22739/external-page-integrated-into-wordpress-returns-a-404-error).

Comment: Ah, this is it!  Thank's so much!

Comment: ok great, I think you got a 404 response when the page was generated and then 200 when the page was already cached with w3tc. You could also add `status_header( 200 );` when you include `wp-blog-header.php` to fix the status. [This thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files) explains the difference between `wp-load.php` and `wp-blog-header.php`.

Comment: This is exactly the information I needed!  If you write it up in an answer, I can award you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With birgire's help, I figured this one out:

The fix was as simple as replacing:

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';
```

with

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../wordpress/wp-load.php';
```

More information in [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22739/external-page-integrated-into-wordpress-returns-a-404-error) from wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your log shows that the http response with the 404 status code in the header is the same response that carries all the data.

This in turn show clearly that the 404 status code is not generated by the server because it didn't find the page, it is generated by some php code in wordpress.

You could look through the code to find the `header()` function, and the debug from there.

Anyway, looking at your website, I cannot reproduce the issue. Either you fixed it, or it was a temporary issue, probaly due to an incompatible plugin or similar.

Comment: It's definitely not fixed or temporary, at least not in my experience.  You just need to make sure you've got the network console running when the page first loads.

I think you're right about that status code being returned artificially by some code in wordpress.  I'll do some digging.  Thanks!

Comment: I assure you that I got a 200 status code. Is it possible that the presence or absence of the trailing slash makes the difference ?

Comment: When I omit the trailing slash, I get a 201 to the url with the slash and then the 404